# create elasticsearch client throws a netty IllegalStateException

Tags: java, elasticsearch, netty

elasticsearch version 5.4.3

I use singleton to create a client , here is the main code

```
TransportClient tclient = null;
    if (clusterName != null) {
            Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                    .put("cluster.name",clusterName)
                    .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                    .build();
            tclient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);//here will throw the exception
    } else {
        tclient = new  PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY);
    }
```

when the first time run to the code "tclient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);",it  throws a exception

[IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7sg7.png)

but invoke that for the second it will success,and client will be ceated,
anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Set the following system property on start:
`System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");`

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-5-4-1-availableprocessors-is-already-set/88036/8